# Is memory mapping required when developing VFS in linux

Tags: linux, memory, vfs

I am developing a virtual file system and a lot of things require memory mapping such as running executables in the mounted directory. Is there a way to disable memory mapping for a VFS so it is required to use the read and write methods and avoids memory mapping all together

Thanks